# AVPlayer buffering video (Play and Pause)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, avplayer

My app uses AVPlayer to play streaming video. However when it buffers, the play button changes it's state to pause mode and I have to set it back to play mode manually. Is there any solution for this?

```
[mPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[mPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

in observeValueForKeyPath method

```
if (!mPlayer)
{
    return;
}

else if (object == mPlayerItem && [path isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])
{
    if (mPlayerItem.playbackBufferEmpty) {
        //Your code here
    }
}

else if (object == mPlayerItem && [path isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
{
    if (mPlayerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?